# Tensorflow with poets

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have questions to ask about why tensorflow with poets was not able to classify the image i want. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with tensorflow installed using docker. Here is my story:

After a successful retrained on flower category following this link [here.](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/#6) I wish to train on my own category as well, I have 10 classes of images and they are well organized according to the tutorial. My photos were also stored in the tf_files directory and following the guide i retrain the inception model on my category.

Everything on the retraining went well. However, as I tired to classify the image I want, I was unable to do so and I have this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niwI0.jpg). I also tried to look for py file in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py but my dist-packages were empty! Can someone help me in this! Where can I find the py files? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your error indicates that it is unable to locate the file. I would suggest you to execute the following command in the directory where you have the graph and label files

```
python label_image.py exact_path_to_your_testimage_file.jpg
```